# What do you call the little black nub on the end of a scanner's USB cable?

Tags: cables, usb-device, equipment

This a scanner's USB cable , I'm wondering what's the little black nub on the end of the cable and what's it for ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a ferrite bead. It is there to help with EMI performance and high frequency noise.
[Link to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead)